# Cannot change vncserver default geometry

Tags: linux, ubuntu, remote-desktop, xorg, vnc

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (I think it's desktop...) and running `vncserver` to connect to it remotely. I can successfully set the resolution if I use the `-geometry` flag when starting the server, but I can't get it to change the default so I don't have to set the flag every time. The manual suggests to use the `$HOME/.vnc/xstartup` file so I made the following change:

```
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 1400x850 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
```

As you can see I tried to make the default '1400x850', a resolution which worked just fine when supplied by the command line. I've even tried setting this resolution in some other files which were the solutions on other OS's, but that didn't work either.

This should be a fairly straightforward thing, what is going wrong here? Does it have something to do with desktop versus server edition? Or my X configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to make a `$HOME/.vncrc` file with this entry: `$geometry = "1400x850";`

Details can be found in the documentation here:

`/usr/share/doc/vnc4server/examples/vnc.conf.gz`

Comment: I'm glad you found this, I'm going to use it myself. You'd think that .vncrc would be mentioned in the vncserver man page.

Comment: Quick note that for TigerVNC server, the file is at $HOME/.vnc/tigervnc.conf. Otherwise this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The xstartup file is used to specify alternative commands to run after a vncserver is started. You could start an xterm with a specific geometry, but it won't change the geometry of the vncserver itself. `vncserver` doesn't read any configuration files, as far as I can tell.

However, it sounds like your ultimate goal is to save yourself some time, and not have to type `-geometry 1400x850` each time.

If that's the case, I would add this to your `$HOME/.profile`:

```
alias myvnc="vncserver -geometry 1400x850 $@"
```

Then you just need to run `myvnc` and it'll start your vnc server for you. You can also add any `vncserver` arguments to the myvnc command and still not need to type the -geometry.
Ex:

```
myvnc :6 -name "My desktop is the best desktop"
```

If you want it to work for all users (and you have root access), you can put it in `/etc/profile` instead.

Comment: Not perfect, but a good answer

Answer (score 0):

On RHEL in my **~/.vnc/config** file  I set

```
geometry=1360x768
```

but the value was being completely ignored on startup of vncserver ...and it was driving me crazy.

I tried

```
xrandr -s 1360x768
```

which worked! ...but on restart of vncserver it again reverted to the incorrect geometry :(

I then discovered that I could set the geometry via the gnome gui using:

> Applications => Settings => Displays => Resolution

And the set resolution persisted on reboot - which is exactly what I wanted.

After more digging, I discovered that the file **~/.config/monitors.xml** is created / changed when changing the settings via gnome above.

Deleting **~/.config/monitors.xml** and rebooting had the following result:

1. The .vnc/config geometry=1360x768 now applies correctly
2. Gnome Applications => Settings => Displays => Resolution reflects the value 1360x768

which is exactly what I needed.